# How to jump into lines in Python?

Tags: python

I want to know if there is a command that would help me go to a specific line and skip other lines, something like the following:

```
if [x] in database1: (the command I need)

skipping other lines.......
to go here:

if [x] in database1: print ' Thank you ' + name + ' :)\n'  <<<< which is in line 31
```

---

EDIT: added code from [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/MY55yBbE)

```
print ' Note: Write your Name and Surname with the first leter, BIG !'
print ' ...'

name = raw_input('Name: ')
surname = raw_input('Surname: ')

print name + ' ' + surname + ',' + ' The Great !\n'

print ' Did you like this ?'

x = raw_input('Yes/No : ')
print ''

database = [
    ['No'],
    ['no']
]
database1 = [
    ['Yes'],
    ['yes']
]
if [x] in database: print ' Did you really meant that ?'
if [x] in database: y = raw_input('Yes/No : ')

# (I need the command here to go that line :)


if [y] in database1: print ' So you'll be dead ' + name + ' !\n'
if [y] in database: print ' Oh OK, Than your free to go ' + name + ' :)'

if [x] in database1: print ' Thank you ' + name + ' :)\n'
if [x] in database1: print 'Try (No) next time !\n'
```

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no such command. It is known as a [`goto`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goto) and pretty much only occured in very early programming language. It is [never necessary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_program_theorem): you can always achieve the same effect with a combination of `if` and `while` (or, more Pythonically, `for`), and [considered harmful](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/ewd02xx/EWD215.PDF) by many.

The reason it is oft abused is that it makes the flow of the program difficult to follow. When reading a normal (structured) program it is easy to tell where control will flow: either around a while loop, into a method call, or split by a conditional. When reading a program using `goto`, though, the control can jump arbitrarily around the program.

In your case, you could either enclose all the intermediate lines inside a conditional, or else refactor the second line into a separate function:

```
def thank(x, name):
    if [x] in database1:
        print 'Thank you, {0}:\n'.format(name)
```

(P.S. Are you sure you mean `[x] in database1` and not `x in database1`?)

---

EDIT: Here's an edited version of the code you put into [your pastebin](http://pastebin.com/MY55yBbE):

```
print 'Enter your name and surname:'

# `.title()` makes first letter capital and rest lowercase
name = raw_input('Name: ').title()
surname = raw_input('Surname: ').title()

# use `.format(...)` to create fancy strings
print '{name} {surname}, the Great!'.format(name=name, surname=surname)

noes = ['no', 'n']
yesses = ['yes', 'y']

print 'Did you like this?'

# `.lower()` for lowercase
if raw_input('Yes/No: ').lower() in noes:
    print 'Did you really mean that?'
    if raw_input('Yes/No : ') in yesses: 
        print 'So you\'ll be dead, {name}!'.format(name=name)
    else:
        print 'Oh, OK, then you\'re free to go, {name}.'.format(name=name)
else:
    print 'Thank you, {name}.'.format(name=name)
    print 'Try "no" next time!'
```

Comment: @altin: I've copied the code from your pastebin into this question so they are associated. In short, the answer is: use `else`!

Comment: +1 for remembering to escape the apostrophes when the OP did not.

Answer (score 1):

### Best Example for Substitute GOTO function in Python

```
def L1():

    a = 10

    print(a)

def L2():

    b = 100

    print(b)

var = str(input("Give your choice, True, False?"))

if var == 'True':
   L1()

else :

    L2()
```

---

Comment: Please format your code appropriately to make it easy for us to read your answer.

Answer (score -1):

If you're just debugging, the easiest way to skip lines, in my opinion, is to comment out those lines temporarily. Just add `#` at the beginning of all the lines you want to skip.

```
if [x] in database1:
     code to execute

# code to skip

if [x] in database1: print ' Thank you ' + name + ' :)\n'
```