# How do I skip the code until the certain line

Tags: python

I'm making a game and every time I need to test it, I need to go over the same thing a million times and I cant just copy the thing I want to test because I need quite a lot of information written in my code. Is there any command like "skip(line(653))" or something like that.

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480926/how-to-jump-into-lines-in-python or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51583897/skipping-lines-of-code-in-python or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42337284/python-skip-a-block-of-code-calculation-when-certain-condition-is-met-without or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59831336/skip-a-chunk-of-code-if-a-condition-is-true-in-python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Design your program as a series of functions and write a test case for the one in question!
https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#basic-example

```sh
python3 -m unittest.discover testpath/
```

Alternatively, if you need live data, you can start your program with PDB (https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html), breakpoint where you like, and then run your function live

```sh
python3 -m pdb myscript.py
...
b 653
c  # continue to line
```